# How to derive (in)equalities from each other in a notationally sound way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, soft-question, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

In elementary algebra and beyond, we are taught to use a sequence of equations to derive a relationship. For instance, to show that $a \le 2b - 1$ follows from $\frac{a+1}{2} = b$, one would use the following sequence of equations, where each equation follows from the previous one.

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a + 1}{2} &= b
\newline
a + 1 &= 2b
\newline
a &= 2b-1
\newline
a &\le 2b - 1
\end{align}
$$

This notation has always seemed inadequate to me. In particular, when I don't want to waste paper I find myself placing multiple equations in one row with an arrow in between them.

$$a = b \Rightarrow c = d $$

This looks nice but does not mean what I want it to mean since in logic

$$a \Rightarrow b \Rightarrow c $$

evaluates to a single value,

$$a \Rightarrow (b \Rightarrow c) $$

whereas I am using it as a short hand for something like

$$
\begin{align}
&1. \:& & a
\newline
&2. \:& & a \Rightarrow b
\newline
&3. \:& & b \Rightarrow c
\newline
&4. \:& \therefore \: & \: c
\end{align}
$$

I've sometimes used the symbol $\rightarrow$ as in

$$a = b \rightarrow c = d $$

but what I really want is to chain implications so that I am emphasizing the nature of my derivation as being a logical progression.

I've also used $\equiv$ as in

$$a = b \equiv c = d $$

but this does not work in many situations such as deriving $a \le 2b - 1$ from $a = 2b - 1$.

Am I overthinking this? Should I just use the typical chain of equations with no symbol to represent the relationship between those equations? Are any of the aforementioned shorthand notations appropriate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a soft-answer.

I think (from your choice of the tags propositional-logic and predicate-logic, and from your remark " in logic ...evaluates to a single value") that you are not so much overthinking this as confused about the use of the symbol $\implies$ when we are writing in the mathematical dialect of English. It is *not* a logical symbol in the whatever-calculus, it is just a convenient abbreviation for "which implies" or "which in turn implies".

So the way we should read

$P\implies  Q \implies R$

is

"$P$ implies $Q$, which in turn implies $R$".

Comment: This is exactly how I'd like to use the symbol. But is this a proper or typical way to use the symbols? Will anyone who reads my work understand that I am using the symbols this way or will they interpret it as an abuse of notation?

Comment: It was typical when I was teaching. I would count "$P\to Q$" as part of an English sentence an abuse of notation, as $\to$ lives in the language of Formal Logic. I would also count such things as $X^2 -1 \implies (X-1)(X+1)$ as an abuse of notation; it is not shorthand for "simplifies to".

Comment: Hmm. One one hand, if it's typical then I should be safe using it since people will understand what I mean. On the other hand, I want to write properly and if it's improper to mix logical symbols with "English safe" symbols, maybe I should avoid those symbols altogether, unless I am going to write entirely in FL. I guess I should think about where this boundary between the two languages lies.

Comment: You do mention that there is a mathematical dialect of English which renders mixed expressions valid, but you also would consider this an abuse of notation? Would that mean mixing other mathematical symbols with English should be avoided, and if not, what distinguishes symbols that are safe to mix with English with those that aren't? Anyway, thank you for your answer. I'll accept it since it addresses the intention of my question.

Comment: Your second comment deserves thought, and it's right to clarify this for oneself. As to you first comment, I (personally) don't think $\implies$ is a symbol of FL, we (well lots of us) use $\to$ in FL. I use $\implies$ as a mathematical english abbreviation. I don't think we can (as you suggest) write mathematics "in FL"; first FL is part of mathematics, second the 'mathematics' (as I see it) is connecting the semantics (model theory) with the syntactics (the formal language and logical calculus). But as a more famous man said, "there is no room in the margin" to develop these ideas!

Answer (score 1):

What you are using repeatedly is the transitivity of implication, that is :

" IF $( A\rightarrow B)\land (B\rightarrow C)$ THEN $(A\rightarrow C)$".

Solving an equation/ inequation can be seen as a reasoning :

(1) ***If the solution set of this expression is not empty***, then ... then ... then the solution set has to be ...

(2) A) The solution set I have found works : I have solved the equation / inequation

(2) B) The solution set I have found does not work , there is no solution, since my reasoning showed the solution set to which I arrived was the only possible one.

What I mean is that the chain of implications only allows to arrive at a necessary condition as to the solution set. For we are working under the hypothesis that the equation / inequation can be solved.

Reference :  Richarson , *Fundamentals of mathematics* ( at available at archive.org)

Comment: I appreciate your insight, although my question is more about notation and convention then semantics. Would you be able to clarify a little more with regard to these aspects of your answer, or provide a recommended notation for the sort of reasoning used in you answer?